Cannot get Binary Tree to Build Correctly for Project in CMSC 315
Edit: I have corrected my code and the errors have been corrected.  I have updated the code in this question with the correct code.
I am stuck on a homework assignment.  I have to be able to read in a preorder representation foo a binary tree and determine whether it is a balanced binary search tree.  It needs to print it in indented form.  I have written this over and over at least 5 times and cannot get it right.  I have attached my latest version as well as the requirements for the project.
// Binary Tree Class
import java.util.*;

public class BinaryTree {
    private Node root;
    private int currentIndex;
    
    //no-arg constructor for best practice
    public BinaryTree() {
        
    }
    
    //Constructor that takes a string and constructs a tree
    public BinaryTree(String userInput) throws InvalidTreeException {
        currentIndex = 0;
        root = createTree(userInput);
        displayTree(root, 0);
    }
    
    //Construcor that takes in an AL of ints and makes a balanced tree 
    public BinaryTree(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
        root = createBalancedBST(list, 0, list.size() - 1);
        displayTree(root, 0);
    }
    
    private void validateString(String s) throws InvalidTreeException {
        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
        
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            //If a char is not a valid input char
            if(!Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i)) && 
                    s.charAt(i) != '(' && s.charAt(i) != ')' && 
                    s.charAt(i) != '*' && s.charAt(i) != ' ') {
                throw new InvalidTreeException("Error - unknown character found in string (" + s.charAt(i) + ")");
            }
            //Detect extra space at beginning of string or any any extra spaces that would throw off input reading
            else if((i == 0 && s.charAt(i) == ' ') ||
                    (i > 1 && (s.charAt(i - 1) == ' ' && s.charAt(i) == ' ')))
                throw new InvalidTreeException("Error - extra spaces detected");
            
            else if(s.charAt(i) == '(') 
                stack.push(s.charAt(i));
            //Missing a right parantheses
            else if(s.charAt(i) == ')') {
                if(stack.isEmpty()) 
                    throw new InvalidTreeException("Error - Missing a left parenthesis.");
            }
            
            //Missing a left parantheses
            else if(i == s.length() - 1 && !stack.isEmpty()) {
                if(stack.peek() == '(') 
                    throw new InvalidTreeException("Error - Missing a right parenthesis.");
            }
        }
    }
    
    private Node createTree(String s) throws InvalidTreeException {
        //Use currentIndex to move through the string and find the end index for node/subtrees
        //Use start as the beginning point to the index
        validateString(s);
        currentIndex = 0;
        int start = currentIndex;
        
        //Remove outer () if the string is greater than one character
        if(s.length() > 1 && s.charAt(0) == '(') 
            s = s.substring(1, s.length() - 1);
        else 
            return null;
        
        
        //Want to find the amount of string that is actually a number to set the new node
        //So from start to currentIndex will have the value for a new node
        while(currentIndex < s.length() && Character.isDigit(s.charAt(currentIndex))) {
            currentIndex++;
        }
        
        //Create a node if the portion of the string was a number
        int value = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(start, currentIndex));
        Node node = new Node(value);
        
        
        //Use stack to find the index for the left and right subtree
        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
        currentIndex++; //skip the space
        start = currentIndex;
        for(int i = currentIndex; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if(s.charAt(i) == '(') 
                stack.push(s.charAt(i));
            else if(s.charAt(i) == ')') {
                if(!stack.isEmpty() && stack.peek() == '(') {
                    stack.pop();
            
                    if(stack.isEmpty()) {
                        currentIndex = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        if(start != currentIndex && currentIndex > start) {
            String leftSubstring = s.substring(start, currentIndex + 1);
            String rightSubstring = s.substring(currentIndex + 2);
            node.left = createTree(leftSubstring);
            node.right = createTree(rightSubstring);
        }
            return node;
    }
    
    //Create new tree from ArrayList values
    private Node createBalancedBST(ArrayList<Integer> list, int start, int end) {
        if(list.isEmpty()) return null;
        else if(start > end) return null;
        else if(list.get(start) == list.get(end)) return new Node(list.get(start)); 
        
        int midpoint = (start + end) / 2;
        Node node = new Node(list.get(midpoint));
        node.left = createBalancedBST(list, start, midpoint - 1);
        node.right = createBalancedBST(list, midpoint + 1, end);
        return node;
    }
    
    //Outputs the indented tree 
    public void displayTree(Node node, int level) {
        if (node == null) return;

        for (int i = 0; i < level; i++)
            System.out.print("    ");
        System.out.println(node.element);
        displayTree(node.left, level + 1);
        displayTree(node.right, level + 1);
    }
    
    //Determines if it's a binary search tree
    public boolean isBST(Node node) {
        if(node == null)
            return true;
        else if(node.left != null && node.element < (node.left).element)
            return false;
        else if(node.right != null && node.element > (node.right).element)
            return false; 
        boolean left = isBST(node.left);
        boolean right = isBST(node.right);
        return left && right;
    } 
    
    //Determines if its a balanced tree
    public boolean isBalanced(Node node) {
        if(node ==  null)
            return false;
        int leftHeight = height(node.left);
        int rightHeight = height(node.right);
        int balanceFactor = Math.abs(leftHeight - rightHeight);
        if(balanceFactor == 1 || balanceFactor == 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    
    //Get the height of the bst
    public int height() {
        return height(root);
    }
    
    //height helper method
    public int height(Node root) {
        Node current = root;
        int left = 0, right = 0;
        
        if(current == null)
            return -1;
        left = height(current.left);
        right = height(current.right);
        if(left > right)
            return left + 1;
        else
            return right + 1;
    }
    
    //Returns an arraylist of values from the tree (use this in the second constructor?
    public ArrayList<Integer> toArray() {
        Node current = root;
        ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
        toArray(arr, current);
        
        //check if bst if not need to sort the array list 
        if(!isBST(root)) arr.sort(null);
        
        return arr;
    }
    
    public void toArray(ArrayList<Integer> arr, Node node){
        if(node != null) {
            toArray(arr, node.left);
            arr.add(node.element);
            toArray(arr, node.right);
        }
    }
    
    public Node getRoot() {
        return this.root;
    }
    
    private static class Node {
        private int element;
        private Node left;
        private Node right;
        
        //no-arg constructor
        private Node() {
            
        }
        
        private Node(Integer e) {
            this.element = e;
        }
    }
}

    

// Main Class or BinaryTreeApp class
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.*;

public class DetermineBalancedBST {

    public static String moreTrees = "Y";
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        String bstInput;
        Scanner reader = null;
        int originalHeight = 0;
        
        while(moreTrees.equals("Y")) {
            try {
                //Take in user input
                System.out.print("Enter a binary tree: ");
                reader = new Scanner(System.in);
                bstInput = reader.nextLine();
                
                //Call tree constructor to construct a tree
                BinaryTree tree = new BinaryTree(bstInput);
                
                //Determine if the tree is a binary search tree and/or balanced
                String message = tree.isBST(tree.getRoot()) && 
                        tree.isBalanced(tree.getRoot()) ? "It is a balanced binary search tree." : 
                            tree.isBST(tree.getRoot()) ? "It is a binary search tree but it is not balanced." :
                                "It is not binary search tree.";
                System.out.println(message);
                
                //If the tree is not a bst or it is not balanced
                if(!tree.isBST(tree.getRoot()) || !tree.isBalanced(tree.getRoot())) {
                    originalHeight = tree.height();
                    BinaryTree newTree = new BinaryTree(tree.toArray());
                    System.out.printf("Original tree has height %d\nBalanced tree has height %d\n", originalHeight, newTree.height());
                }
                
                //Ask if user wants more trees:
                System.out.print("More trees? Y or N: ");
                moreTrees = reader.nextLine();
                while(!moreTrees.equals("Y") && !moreTrees.equals("N")) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input, try again.");
                    System.out.print("More trees? Y or N: ");
                    moreTrees = reader.nextLine();
                }
            } 
            catch (InvalidTreeException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }
        reader.close();
        System.out.println("Thank you!!!!");
    }

}




[

"I cannot get it right": can you turn this into a precise question? What exactly is not right? Can you provide the input that must be given to this program so that it reproduces the problem? What is expected as output and what happens instead? What have you found out when launching your debugger, setting breakpoints and inspecting variables? Please share the results of your debugging session.
